# How to make column values negative if False in another column

Tags: r

I have been searching around quite a bit but don't seem to be able to find a solution to my problem.

This is the dataset we are talking about:

```
   NS    WE  LatCopy  LongCopy
FALSE FALSE 48.89328  5.803433
TRUE  FALSE 48.55725  6.877400
TRUE  FALSE 48.39922  9.383667
FALSE TRUE  48.37538  9.517017
TRUE  FALSE 48.20710 12.324067
TRUE  TRUE  48.16878 12.822067
```

Since these are coordinates, I had to scrap the wind directions in order to convert them to Decimal degrees. However, I don't have the - indicator now.

The result I am looking for is something like this:

```
   NS    WE  LatCopy  LongCopy
FALSE FALSE 48.89328 -5.803433
TRUE  FALSE 48.55725 -6.877400
TRUE  FALSE 48.39922 -9.383667
FALSE TRUE -48.37538  9.517017
TRUE  FALSE 48.20710 -12.32406
TRUE  TRUE 48.16878 -12.82206
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="NS    WE  LatCopy  LongCopy
FALSE FALSE 48.89328  5.803433
TRUE  FALSE 48.55725  6.877400
TRUE  FALSE 48.39922  9.383667
FALSE TRUE  48.37538  9.517017
TRUE  FALSE 48.20710 12.324067
TRUE  TRUE  48.16878 12.822067",h=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have a variety of possibilities, a `dplyr` solution:

```
data %>%
  mutate(LatCopy = ifelse(NS, LatCopy, -LatCopy),
         LongCopy = ifelse(WE, LongCopy, -LongCopy))
```

A `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(data)[, LatCopy := ifelse(NS, LatCopy, -LatCopy)
            ][, LongCopy := ifelse(WE, LongCopy, -LongCopy)]
```

Comment: The first option worked, I removed the pipe operator and did it separately since the columns have to be overwritten. But thanks!

Comment: since you're not using the pipe, base R would be `data <- transform(data, LatCopy = ifelse(NS, LatCopy, -LatCopy),
         LongCopy = ifelse(WE, LongCopy, -LongCopy))` . You can overwrite with the pipe as well though, `data <- data %>% ...`

Comment: As @Moody_Mudskipper already noticed, you can simply overwrite the data with `data <- data %>% ...`.

Comment: df$LatCopy <- ifelse(df$NS, df$LatCopy, -1*df$LatCopy) This did the trick, inspired by @tmfmnk

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sign` with a slight tweak :

```
df[c("LongCopy", "LatCopy")]  <- 
  df[c("LongCopy", "LatCopy")] * sign(.5-df[c("NS","WE")]) # or `2*` instead of sign
#      NS    WE   LatCopy   LongCopy
# 1  TRUE FALSE  48.89328  -5.803433
# 2  TRUE FALSE  48.55725  -6.877400
# 3  TRUE FALSE  48.39922  -9.383667
# 4 FALSE  TRUE -48.37538   9.517017
# 5  TRUE FALSE  48.20710 -12.324067
# 6  TRUE FALSE  48.16878 -12.822067
```

Comment: This only seems to work when there is a difference between NS and WE, but when both are true the output is two negatives, opposite for false. Any fix to that?

Comment: I don't understand you, don't you want FALSE to be converted to a negative value in the other column ? I see now that your question doesn't contain an actual question , just this example :), so i can't do more than replicate it. What do you want to do ?

Comment: maybe you could update your example with a case where my solution fails ?

Comment: For sure. 

Just to clarify: When NS and WE are false, it seems like LatCopy and LongCopy are both positive values whilst they should be negative. When NS and WE are true, LongCopy and LatCopy are negative, but should be positive.

Comment: can you confirm that the first line of your new expected output is correct ? having both FALSE changed LongCopy but didn't change LatCopy

Comment: Yes, the output of the first line was indeed correct. Having both FALSE didn't change anything, both TRUE made both negative.

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe$LatCopy  <- ifelse(dataframe$WE == TRUE, -dataframe$LatCopy, dataframe$LatCopy)
dataframe$LongCopy <- ifelse(dataframe$NS == TRUE, -dataframe$LongCopy , dataframe$LongCopy )
```

you can try something like this? I don't have R open so I can't test it but this is where I would start.

Comment: Since NS & WE are already logical, it is perhaps simpler to leave off the `== TRUE` parts

Comment: The issue is that the unary operator "-" is invalid according to R, I just tried it.

Comment: oh yes, Alexis made  a mistake, it should be `-dataframe$LatCopy`

Comment: yea I'll change it